# Problems to send parameters for $_POST['whatever'] to PHP file

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am trying to send a POST to a file php to insert some values in mysql database. When I send the parameters the if($_POST['nombre']){...} receive the $_POST with null value. I am stuck. Here is the code

**JSONParse.java**

```
public class JSONParser {

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection= null;
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, ContentValues params) {

        try {
            if(method == "POST"){
                URL url1= new URL(url);
                urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.connect();
                is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            }else if(method == "GET"){
                url += "?" + params;
                URL url1= new URL(url);
                urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();
                is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jObj;

    }
}
```

**AltaUserFragment.java`**

```
public class AltaUserFragment extends Fragment {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_USERS = "usuarios";
    private static final String TAG_USER = "usuario";
    private static final String TAG_CONTRA = "contrasena";

    JSONArray users = null;
    private ContentValues params;

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    private static String url_alta_user = "https://serverhost/android/create_user.php";

    public AltaUserFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alta_user, container, false);
        Button btnAlta = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAltaUser);
        btnAlta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new AltaUsario().execute();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    class AltaUsario extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        TextView txtNombre = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
        TextView txtUsuario = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtUsuario);
        TextView txtEmail = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        TextView txtContra1 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtContra1);
        TextView txtContra2 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtContra2);

        String nombre = txtNombre.getText().toString();
        String usuario = txtUsuario.getText().toString();
        String email = txtEmail.getText().toString();
        String contra1 = txtContra1.getText().toString();
        String contra2 = txtContra2.getText().toString();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Checking user. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            params = new ContentValues();
            params.put("nombre",nombre );
            params.put("usuario",usuario );
            params.put("contrasena", contra1 );
            params.put("email",email);

            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_alta_user, "POST", params);

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();

                } else {

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
`
```

**create_user.php**

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$con = new DB_CONNECT();
$con->connect();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['usuario']) && isset($_POST['contrasena']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysqli_query($con->myconn, "INSERT INTO users(nombre, usuario, contrasena, email) VALUES('$nombre', '$usuario', '$contrasena', '$email')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "User successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: You misst "&&" in your first PHP `if` request write it like that: `if (isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['usuario']) && isset($_POST['contrasena']) && isset($_POST['email']))` or write it like `if (isset($_POST['nombre'],$_POST['usuario'],$_POST['contrasena'],$_POST['email']))`

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I am receiving null value to any of them.

Comment: I change the code. I put it with &&. It was a dismiss when I pasted the code

Comment: try `print_r($_REQUEST);` on the first line of create_user.php and see what you are getting

Comment: I receive "Array"

Comment: "Array\n(\n)\n"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with "POST". You should consider using volley library https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html, I think it can solve your problem.
In your app gradle add the required dependencies and use volley methods when a button is clicked

```
insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String feedback = feed.getText().toString();
            if(feedback.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"please fill all fields",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            final ProgressDialog loading =
                    ProgressDialog.show(feedbackPage.this, "Setting up connection...", null, true, true);
            //delay insertion by x sec so that course code can be properly fetched
            mhandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(loading.isShowing())
                        loading.dismiss();
                    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insert_url,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {

                                    dialog.setTitle("Server Response");
                                    dialog.setMessage(response);
                                    dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                            feed.setText("");
                                        }
                                    });
                                    AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
                                    alert.show();
                                }
                            }
                            , new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            Toast.makeText(feedbackPage.this, "error...." + error.toString()
                                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }) {
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            params.put("uid", uid);
                            params.put("name", userName);
                            params.put("feed", feedback);
                            return params;
                        }
                    };

                    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(3000, 5,
                            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

                    Singleton.getInstance(feedbackPage.this).addTorequestqueue(request);
                }
            },3000);
        }
    });
```

You need a singleton class to get the request queue in return:

```
public class Singleton {

private static Singleton single_instance;
private RequestQueue queue;
private static Context ctx;

private Singleton(Context ctx){
    this.ctx=ctx;
    queue = getQueue();
}

public static synchronized Singleton getInstance( Context ctx){
    if(single_instance == null){
        single_instance = new Singleton(ctx);
    }
    return single_instance;

}

public RequestQueue getQueue(){
    if(queue==null){
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx.getApplicationContext());
        return queue;
    }

    return queue;
}

public <T>void addTorequestqueue(Request<T> request){
    queue.add(request);
}
```

you can better understand it on : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FL37oah1k8k

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

If you access the `POST` data in PHP using `$_POST`, it mean you need to use `x-www-form-urlencoded` in request header.

I see you missed set `Content-Type` of `HttpURLConnection`. Please add this line to `public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(...)` function

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Comment: Thansk but no way. It does not work. Still null value

Comment: if you still get them as `null`, seem java still not sent data correctly

Answer (score 0):

You should use this :

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstParam", paramValue1));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("secondParam", paramValue2));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("thirdParam", paramValue3));
//...

JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params);
```

Anyway you are doing this in a wrong way , **Apache Http Client** is not supported anymore from version api **21** if i am not worng , and **NameValuePair** is deprecated . I wanna suggest you to read something about **Volley**(google library) or similar .

Comment: List<NameValuePair> is deprecated.

Comment: As i said above

Comment: I know. But you wrote a code that is not in my code. Thanks. I am looking Volley.

Comment: I don't know from where you took this code , but i seen somewhere before and i used too for training in past , i remember that with NameValuePair was working well .

Comment: It is mine. Thanks. Just one question. Volley needs to work with AsuncTask or it is possible without it?

Comment: Don't need , read about it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Comment: Thanks s alot for your help. I really apreciate it!